# Visual Studio 2015 and ReSharper - Mouse cursor repeatedly loading while trying to show intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper

So this is one of the most irritating things I've encountered, and I'm 100% sure it's because of ReSharper (i tried installing/uninstalling ReSharper and it was fixed when it was gone).

While I type, and when ReSharper tries displaying IntelliSense, mouse cursor starts rapidly loading (like 5-6 times in 2 seconds) as if it's trying to load something. Project is not too big, and there's not too many classes. Also time it takes to display IntelliSense has slowed down.

I have no clue how to fix this, I've tried googling for this problem but to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Resharper is pretty 'expensive' resources-wise, so if your machine isn't powerful enough, you'll see that happening.
Perhaps try setting down some of the features of resharper, such as CodeAnalysis, Cyclomatic complexity etc.

Maybe disable some other VS Extensions running in background, if you have any?

Comment: I thought about that, but this machine has i7, SSD and dedicated GPU, so I don't think that's a problem. It also worked all fine, but then there was some kind of Windows 10 update (so it seems) that messed up everything including SQL Server, Visual Studio, and my Version Control software.

Comment: I'm sorry man, but this still seems like a performance issue, I doubt there is an tickbox in R# 'load faster'. There is a checkbox in 'General' tab that says `Show memory usage in status bar`, maybe have a look at what values you get? (mine is around 400-600 MB)